# error: no match for ‘operator<<’

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is driving me nuts...
I have a header a.h with the following contents

```
#if !defined(PRETTY_PRINT_H)
#define PRETTY_PRINT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int> v);

#endif
```

a source b.cc with

```
...
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"
...
void
ns::ClD::myfunc(args...) {
  const std::vector<int> test(2,1);
  ...
  std::cout << "test : " << test << std::endl;
  ...
}
...
```

and a header b.h

```
...
namespace ns {
    class ClD: public ClB
    private:
      virtual void
      myfunc(args...);
     ...
```

When compiling b.cc, I get

```
b.cc: In member function ‘virtual void myfunc()’:
b.cc:134:26: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘const std::vector<int>’)
   std::cout << "test : " << test << std::endl;
                          ^
b.cc:134:26: note: candidates are:
...
```

**UPDATE**

There were candidates coming from my header (the line number would not match, since I removed a few commented and blank lines in this OP).

For the cases where the issue is with argument 1, e.g.,

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
                 from a.h:12,
                 from b.cc:13:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:108:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:108:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::vector<int>’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&) {aka std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:117:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:117:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::vector<int>’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}’
...
```

For the cases where the issue is with argument 2,

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
                 from a.h:12,
                 from b.cc:13:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:548:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const unsigned char* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:548:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
b.cc:135:29: note:   cannot convert ‘test’ (type ‘const std::vector<int>’) to type ‘const unsigned char*’
   std::cout << "test : " << test << std::endl;
                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
                 from a.h:12,
                 from b.cc:13:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:543:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const signed char* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:543:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
b.cc:135:29: note:   cannot convert ‘test’ (type ‘const std::vector<int>’) to type ‘const signed char*’
   std::cout << "test : " << test << std::endl;
                             ^
...
```

But I am not sure if any of the candidates analyzed in the reported messages actually come from my prototype or from others from included standard headers.

Any hints on what the problem is?

Comment: Is your operator perchance declared in a namespace that is not global?

Comment: When reduced to a [bare minimum](http://ideone.com/n3Xg1n) it works. So whatever the problem is, your code snippets don't demonstrate it.

Comment: The error is probably in one of your "..."   When you don't know what the problem is, assuming that things aren't the problem is often the problem.   The code compiles: https://godbolt.org/g/AKHBPK

Comment: @krzaq - No. I have reduced the contents of the header to a minimum, and now I have posted the complete header, so you can see.

Comment: You also left out an important part of the error message, the one after `note: candidates are:`. Is your overload listed there? If it is, doesn't it tell you why it's not a match?

Comment: @sancho.s it certainly doesn't match the error message though. How can a free function be `virtual`?

Comment: @StoryTeller - You are right. And there are likely quite a few candidate reasons embedded into the "..."s

Comment: @Ionut - Please see updated OP. I could not understand that as a hint for the compilation error. There were many other reported "attempts".
I am not sure if any of the candidates analyzed in the reported messages actually come from my prototype or from others from included standard headers.

Comment: @BoPersson, Shouldn't the bare minimum example I linked to face similar issues, than?

Comment: @BoPersson - I do not understand if you mean that my prototype is not actually considered...

Comment: @StoryTeller - Yes it would. Then there is more to it than I saw.

Comment: @sancho.s Those you posted are not coming from your header, they're all from `ostream`, your header is just the one that causes ostream to be included. Does your overload appear anywhere in that long list of candidates? If it doesn't that it's not considered at all. If it does, it will tell why it fails to match. My guess is it doesn't, but then you'll have to provide more code to narrow it down (like what other overloads of `operator<<` you might have defined in your code).

Comment: @krzaq - It is declared as virtual, please see updated OP.

Comment: @Ionut - Should the error say `In file included from a.h:15:0,` (i.e., at the top of the inclusion chain) for the candidate to be my prototype?

Comment: @sancho.s No, it should say `In file included from b.cc ...` and the lines containing `note: ...` should have `a.h` at the begining.

Comment: @Ionut - I have found the culprit. It was another overload that was interfering. All comments were useful to pinpoint the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all comments, which guided me to the extra pieces needed to update the OP, and to check behavior of my code, I found the culprit.

There was another overload that was interfering.
In the "..."s, there was an included header that contained

```
namespace ns {
  class ClB2
  {
    ...
  };

  inline
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ClB2& me) {
    (Irrelevant code; when commented still produced the error)
    return os;
  }
}
```

When I moved the overload outside the namespace, as

```
inline
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ns::ClB2& me) {
  (Irrelevant code)
  return os;
}
```

it worked.
Still, I am not certain why this produced the error.